# Serialize Object Order

Tags: c#, serialization

I am trying to Serialize a Class in C# and It works fine now the issue is i want the xml serialization in a particular order and tried using  [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]

but doing so my program starts giving error on execution and works fine if i remove the above statement but then i dont get the elements ordered in the required way.

error : "There was an error reflecting type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Bill'."

### Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "Bill", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Bill 
    {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DocNo")]
        [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)] 
        public string DocNo { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DocDt")]
        [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)] 
        public string DocDt { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Bill-Items")]
        [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 3)] 
        public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DocAmount")]
        [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 4)] 
        public string DocAmount{ get; set; }


        public void Serialize()
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
            x.Serialize(Console.Out, this);
        }

        public void Deserialize()
        {
            BillsCollection bills = null;
            string path = "E:\\data.xml";

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BillsCollection));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            bills = (BillsCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }


        public Bill()
        {
            items.Add(new Item { StockNo = "2323", MRP=234.34,Qty=2 });
            items.Add(new Item { StockNo = "4564", MRP = 1250.00, Qty = 5 });
        }
    }

    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        public string StockNo;
        public double MRP;
        public double Qty;
        public string TaxCode;
        public double TaxAmount;
        public double TaxPercent;
        public string DiscCode;
        public double DiscAmount;
        public double DiscPer;

    }

    public class BillItems
    {
    //    [XmlArray]
    }



    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName="Bills",Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public class BillsCollection
    {
        [XmlArray("Bills")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Bill", typeof(Bill))]
        public Bill[] Bills { get; set; }

        public static void Add(Bill bill )
        {

        }

    }


}

Current Output
---------------
<Bill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Bill-Items>
    <Item>
      <StockNo>2323</StockNo>
      <MRP>234.34</MRP>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <TaxAmount>0</TaxAmount>
      <TaxPercent>0</TaxPercent>
      <DiscAmount>0</DiscAmount>
      <DiscPer>0</DiscPer>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <StockNo>4564</StockNo>
      <MRP>1250</MRP>
      <Qty>5</Qty>
      <TaxAmount>0</TaxAmount>
      <TaxPercent>0</TaxPercent>
      <DiscAmount>0</DiscAmount>
      <DiscPer>0</DiscPer>
    </Item>
  </Bill-Items>
  <DocNo>1</DocNo>
  <DocAmount>2001</DocAmount>
</Bill>


Required Output (Basically Doc No and Doc Amount should be before Item List 
---------------
<Bill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Bill-Items>
  <DocNo>1</DocNo>
  <DocAmount>2001</DocAmount>
    <Item>
      <StockNo>2323</StockNo>
      <MRP>234.34</MRP>
      <Qty>2</Qty>
      <TaxAmount>0</TaxAmount>
      <TaxPercent>0</TaxPercent>
      <DiscAmount>0</DiscAmount>
      <DiscPer>0</DiscPer>
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <StockNo>4564</StockNo>
      <MRP>1250</MRP>
      <Qty>5</Qty>
      <TaxAmount>0</TaxAmount>
      <TaxPercent>0</TaxPercent>
      <DiscAmount>0</DiscAmount>
      <DiscPer>0</DiscPer>
    </Item>
  </Bill-Items>
</Bill>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used same attribute twice:

```
public class Bill 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DocNo")]
    [XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)] 
    public string DocNo { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

Change those to:

```
public class Bill 
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "DocNo", Order = 1)] 
    public string DocNo { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

More info about XmlElementAttribute can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also consider this convention while using attributes. Note is from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) page.

> Note   By convention, all attribute names end with the word
>   "Attribute" to distinguish them from other items in the .NET
>   Framework. However, you do not need to specify the attribute suffix
>   when using attributes in code.

Comment: If it works for you, please mark as an answer to notify others that this is the solution.

Comment: Thanks that worked, Can you even suggest me how to make the node have null values i mean for eg if i do not have node value as of now it is not putting the node name itself in the xml file. like if DocDt is null it should still have node as <DocDt></DocDt>  and also how do i skip this namespace thing <Bill xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Comment: In my opinion, null values should not be skipped by default. If you want to skip namespace, then code below should help you:
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Bill));
                XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                xmlNamespaces.Add("", "");
                serializer.Serialize(writer, billElement, xmlNamespaces);

Comment: Thanks with yours suggestion I was able to remove the namespace from the Bill TAG, As far as DocDt node is concerned i tried this  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("DocDt", Order = 2, IsNullable = true, Namespace="")] Doing so i do get an empty node but this is again with a namespace what can i do to get simply <DocDt></DocDt> if DocDt=Null currently i am getting this  <DocDt d2p1:nil="true" xmlns:d2p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />